# Virtualbox, using the same keybord layout of the host in the guest os

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, virtual-machine, virtualization, keyboard-layout

I'm using Virtualbox 4.1.12 on Debian x64 and my host OS is Windows XP Professional 64-bit.
On Debian I'm using a custom keyboard layout that I set on system startup through the command setxkbmap.
I've already successfully installed the guest addictions.
I would like to use the same keyboard layout of the host in the guest OS.
How can I do?